# How to find the next hourly time using Calendar nextDate method in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to find the next hourly time.
E.g.

Now is: 4/9/16, 10:12:34 AM GMT+10
I want to get: 4/9/16, 11:00:00 AM GMT+10

So I tried using Calendar.current.nextDate, but I got the weird response.
The sample code is as follow.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .long

    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.minute = 0
    dateComponents.second = 0

    let beginDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
    var beginDateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: TimeZone.current, from: beginDate)
    beginDateComponents.minute = 0
    beginDateComponents.second = 0
    let modifiedDate = Calendar.current.date(from: beginDateComponents)!

    let nextHourlyTime = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: modifiedDate, matching: dateComponents, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!

    print("modifiedDate: \(dateFormatter.string(from: modifiedDate))")
    print("beginDate: \(dateFormatter.string(from: beginDate))")
    print("nextHourlyTime: \(dateFormatter.string(from: nextHourlyTime))")

    /*
     modifiedDate: 1/1/70, 10:00:00 AM GMT+10
     beginDate: 1/1/70, 10:00:00 AM GMT+10
     nextHourlyTime: 1/2/70, 12:00:00 AM GMT+10
     */
```

But if I enter comment the code: "dateComponents.second = 0", then I will get the correct answer.

Is there something wrong with Apple's nextDate api?

Answer (score 7):

The error is at your beginDate. It should be set to `Date()` not `Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)`. You can do it as follow:

```
extension Date {
    var nextHourShift: Date? {
        return Calendar.current.nextDate(after: self, matching: DateComponents(minute: 0), matchingPolicy: .nextTime)
    }
}

Date().nextHourShift  // "Sep 3, 2016, 4:00 AM"
```

Comment: Nice elegant code. It does it correctly.
I just can't understand why it doesn't work for "Gregorian.calendar.nextDate(after: self, matching: DateComponents(minute: 0, second: 0), matchingPolicy: .nextTime)"

Comment: Beautifully simple ... I guess we can tell you were on the East coast when you posted the result.  ;-)

Comment: Thank you. I tried using `Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour], from: Date()))` but that wouldn't work.